# How can I float the different definitions in my description list next to each other?

Tags: html, css, dd, dt

So i am trying to make a horizontal timeline. I thought it would be the most logical thing to create a defenition list dl with the years as definition terms dt, and the description as definition description  dd.

When ready, it should look like this:

[Timeline design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CBP2.png)

This is my html code so far:

```
<dl class="timeline">
<dt>1665</dt>
<dd>The first chamber of commerce is established in Bruges. Over the following years and centuries, other chambers of commerce are established on the territory of present-day Belgium. They are private organisations, founded by local traders.</dd>                       
<dt>1791</dt>
<dd>Under French rule, the chambers of commerce and the corporations are dissolved.</dd>
<dt>1802</dt>
<dd>Napoleon reestablished the chambers of commerce.</dd>
</dl>
```

Now i wanna float all the definitions next to each other, without having to create different dl's or something like that. In other words, i try to style the dt with his belonging dd together.

Does anyone know the solution to this problem?

Comment: Sorry to say but I'd be using a different structure here if you want to use floats. You'd have to wrap each `dt/dd` grouping in a separate div and float  those.

Comment: I'd be thinking more in terms of a standard menu structure.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.line {
  float:left;
  width:100px;
  border-left:1px solid;
  padding-left:20px;
  margin-right:30px;
}
.blue {
  border-left:1px solid blue;
  color:blue;
}
.yellow {
  border-left:1px solid yellow;
  color:yellow;
}
.green {
  border-left:1px solid green;
  color:green;
}
.red {
  border-left:1px solid red;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="line blue"><h1>1990</h1><p>Text</p></div>
<div class="line yellow"><h1>1990</h1><p>Text</p></div>
<div class="line green"><h1>1990</h1><p>Text</p></div>
<div class="line red"><h1>1990</h1><p>Text</p></div>
```